# Numpy array return rows based on criteria

Tags: python, numpy

I would like to return the rows of a numpy array where the second value is larger than the second to last value.
For example

```
[[5 0 3 3] 
 [7 9 3 5] 
 [2 4 7 6] 
 [8 8 1 6]]
```

would return

```
[[7 9 3 5]
 [8 8 1 6]]
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create a mask where the 2nd col is greater than 2nd to last col:

```
mask = a[:,1] > a[:,-2]

# array([False,  True, False,  True])
```

And index with the mask:

```
a[mask]

# array([[7, 9, 3, 5],
#        [8, 8, 1, 6]])
```

This is broken into steps for clarity, but of course you can combine them into one expression `a[a[:,1] > a[:,-2]]`.